# How to check the dates in different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe "expeditions" where there are 3 columns ("basecamp_date", "highpoint_date" and "termination_date"). I would like to check that the basecamp date is before the highpoint date and before the termination date because I noticed that there are rows where this is not the case (see picture) [image]
Do you have any idea what I should do (a loop, a new dataframe...?)

Code

```
import pandas as pd
expeditions = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/expeditions.csv")
```

Comment: What's your desired output? Do you want to delete the rows with this condition? Do you want a new column with True or False?

Comment: 2008-01-04 is 4th January or 1st April?

Comment: That's 4th January

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by transforming the columns into a datetime format to be extra sure:

```
for x in df:
  df[x] = pd.to_datetime(df[x],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

And then follow it by the comparison using `np.where()`

```
df['Check'] = np.where((df['basecamp_date'] < df['highpoint_date']) & (df['basecamp_date'] < df['termination_date']),True,False)
```

EDIT: Based on OPs follow up question I propose the following solution:

```
filtered = df[((df['basecamp_date'] < df['highpoint_date']) & (df['basecamp_date'] < df['termination_date'])) | (df.isna().sum(axis=1) != 0)]
```

Example:

```
  basecamp_date highpoint_date termination_date
0    2008-01-04     2008-05-01       2008-04-05
1           NaN     2008-05-03       2008-06-03
2    2008-01-04     2008-01-01       2009-01-01
```

Only row 0 should be kept as row 2 doesn't match that date conditions and row 1 has a null value. Using the proposed code, the output is:

```
  basecamp_date highpoint_date termination_date
0    2008-01-04     2008-05-01       2008-04-05
1           NaT     2008-05-03       2008-06-03
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, do you know how to drop the "False" in Check but not when there are NaT, just only when there are values in every date columns

Comment: Hello, I have edited my answer, please see the edits

Comment: I think I didn't explain enough clearly what I wanted, I know it's weird but I would like to keep the rows with NaN values and not drop them

Comment: Kindly check the approach now. Thank you for clarifying it!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for compare columns and chain masks by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
m = (df['basecamp_date'].ge(df['highpoint_date']) |
             df['basecamp_date'].ge(df['termination_date']) |
             df[['basecamp_date', 'termination_date', 'highpoint_date']].notna().all(1)))
```

)

If need check matched values:

```
df1 = df[m]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, do you know how to drop the "False" in test but not when there are NaT, just only when there are values in every date columns

Comment: Hi Jezrael, great answer as usual. I'm commenting to let you know in thetext you say `&` but in the code you use `|`. I think the correct choice would be `&` for the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your data to `datetime` format:

```
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])
```

and then do like this:

```
df[df['date_col1'] < df['date_col2']]
```

In your case `date_col` might be you column names.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, do you know how to drop the "False" in test but not when there are NaT, just only when there are values in every date columns

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are working solutions but I find this much easier:

```py
df.query("basecamp_date < highpoint_date and basecamp_date
 < termination_date")
```